# Determine if field values meet minimum consecutive years within a year range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Given the following table,

```
 PersonID     Year
---------- ----------
1          1991
1          1992
1          1993
1          1993
2          1990
2          1991
3          1991
3          1992
3          1994
```

Is there a way with a SQL select query to get the PersonID where it has at least 3 rows with consecutive years in the range 1990 to 1995? In this case, it should only find PersonID 1.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using?

Comment: Thanks, 2012. Added the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like the following should work:

```
SELECT personID
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN year - min(year) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY YEAR ASC ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 PRECEDING) = 2 THEN 'x' END as ConsecutiveFlag,
            PersonID
        FROM 
            (SELECT personID, year FROM table GROUP BY personID,year) subquery
        WHERE year BETWEEN 1990 and 1995   
    ) t1
WHERE ConsecutiveFlag = 'x'
GROUP BY personID
```

That uses a Windowing Function to order by date and look two rows back. It compares the current year to the value from two rows previous and if the difference is 2 then we know we have consecutive years.

The outer query filters records that are flagged and returns the personid.

Comment: Great, if it was 4 consecutive years, how would the following part change? ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING

Comment: Change that `ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) = 3` Really you could do `ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 3 PRECEDING) = 3` as well. Since it orders the window by year and we look at at `min(year)` within the window, it's going to return the same.

Comment: This assumes there are no duplicate rows in the table, right?

Comment: There could be duplicate rows. I updated the table in the question to include one for clarity. Could a modification to this answer account for duplicates?

Comment: Instead of `FROM table` above, you could just GROUP BY in a subquery to get distinct values for the Windowing: `FROM (SELECT personID, Year From Table GROUP BY 1,2) as subquery` as a replacement for `FROM table`   I just made the quick change to the answer.

Comment: There are some cases where `ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 3 PRECEDING) = 3` works and `ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) = 3` does not. I appreciate the solution using `OVER`, which has prompted me to read as much as I can on it.

Comment: Once you start using Windowing Functions, you'll find a thousand and one uses for them. You'll also hate every other RDBMS that doesn't use them.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select a.PersonID from Table a
left join Table b
    on a.Personid = b.Personid and a.year = b.year + 1
left join Table c
    on a.Personid = c.Personid and b.year = c.year + 1
where b.year is not null 
    and c.year is not null
    and a.year <= 1995 and c.year >= 1990
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join the table with itself:

```
declare @ConsecutiveYears as integer
set @ConsecutiveYears = 3

select distinct PersonYear.PersonID
from PersonYear
join PersonYear Consecutives
on PersonYear.PersonID = Consecutives.PersonID
    and Consecutives.Year between PersonYear.Year and PersonYear.Year + @ConsecutiveYears - 1
where PersonYear.Year >= 1990 and Consecutives.Year <= 1995
Group by PersonYear.PersonID, PersonYear.Year
Having COUNT(distinct Consecutives.Year) = @ConsecutiveYears
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with 2 `self joins` (you will join the table 3 times on same `personId` and `year` increment by one in each join to find sequenced years 3 time for each person)

*Schema:*

```
create table tbl_so(PersonID int,[Year] int)
insert into tbl_so values
(1,          1991),
(1,          1992),
(1,          1993),
(1,          1993),
(2,          1990),
(2,          1991),
(3,          1991),
(3,          1992),
(3,          1994)
```

*Query:*

```
 select distinct t1.personId
 from tbl_so t1
 join tbl_so t2 on t1.[year]+1=t2.[year] and t1.personId=t2.personId
 join tbl_so t3 on t2.[year]+1=t3.[year] and t2.personId=t3.personId
```

*Output:*

```
personId
1
```